# redirect to another page using a href and spring mvc

Tags: jquery, spring

I want to change page when I click on item in my bootstrap navbar.

I'm trying like this.

```
<li><a href="javascript:" name="mainpage"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Main</a>
```

And with `onclick` method for `a` is.

```
$("ul > li > a").click(function() {
    $.post("redirect.html", { page : this.name } );
});
```

And spring controller is

```
@RequestMapping("/redirect.html")
public String redirect(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams,
        Model model) {
    logger.debug("attempt to redirect");
    String next_page = allRequestParams.get("page");
    logger.debug("Parameter page: " + next_page);
    return "redirect: events";
}
```

In debug window it shows that it enters method `redirect` properly. But the page doesn't change.

**What's the problem?**

The whole navbar looks like this

```
<div id="navbarItems" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="javascript:" name="mainpage"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Main</a>
                        <li><a href="javascript:" name="events"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: what does your controller returns?

Comment: I highly doubt that returning a http-redirect for an AJAX-request, instruct the browser to reload the page out of the box. IMHO this must been implemented in the Java Script repose handler.

Comment: I see. So basically I need to redirect inside javascript? The problem is that I use spring mvc and .jsp which cannot be accessed inside for example `href` so inside javascript I think too . Or can be?